# IE javascript support for shift key down?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard-events

I have a mouse moving over a cell image

```
<td onmouseenter="tdME(1,1)"><img src="row.png"></td>
```

In Chrome I can just examine the global event to see if shift is being held down

```
  function tdME(r, c) {
    if ( event.shiftKey ) {
       // do stuff
    }
  }
```

Does not work in IE 11 though, is there a cross browser way to determine if the shift key is held down for the onmouseenter event?

Comment: If you think that the suggestion given by @Drylchik can help to fix your issue then you can mark his suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetShiftState (event) {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                alert ("Shift key is down.");
            }
            else {
                alert ("Shift key is up.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Press and hold down the SHIFT key before you click on the button.
    <br />
    <button onclick="GetShiftState (event);">Get Shift key state!</button>
</body>
```